# Rewrite Stored Procedure to return instead of median(50%), the items at 20%/30% etc position

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns the median of a set based on some group.

```
SET @myvar:='1';
SET @rownum=0;

SELECT result.readdate, 
       AVG(total_gallons) AS total_gallons
FROM   (SELECT middle_rows.readdate, 
               numerated_rows.rownum, 
               numerated_rows.total_gallons 
        FROM   (SELECT IF(@myvar = readdate, @rownum := IFNULL(@rownum,0) + 1, @rownum := 0) AS rownum,
                       @myvar := readdate                                          AS readdate_alias,
                       total_gallons 
                FROM   _temp_total_gallons 
                ORDER  BY readdate, 
                          total_gallons) numerated_rows, 
               (SELECT readdate, 
                       COUNT(*) / 2 median 
                FROM   _temp_total_gallons
                GROUP  BY readdate) middle_rows 
        WHERE  numerated_rows.rownum BETWEEN ( middle_rows.median - IF(median = ROUND(median), 1, 0) - 0.5 ) AND ( middle_rows.median - IF(median = ROUND(median), 0, 0.5) )
               AND numerated_rows.readdate_alias = middle_rows.readdate) result
GROUP  BY readdate;
```

As you see this uses the BETWEEN clause to return the rows between on 50% position. If multiple rows are found(even set) the outer select does an average.

I've tried changing `COUNT(*) / 2 median` into `COUNT(*) / 5 median` but the query returns a lot smaller data set, probably because the between clause is too strict and does not reflect the 20%.

In a set like:

```
1 (2) 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 100 110
```

The number 2 is at 20%.

In future I would like the script to be usable to return any procent selection like item at 30% or 40%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the info on the following page, the SQL is able to calculate any percentile you wish

http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2008/07/calculating-nth-percentile-in-mysql.html

I've used this myself in a number of areas, and it works really well. You just have to careful with the value of the 'group_concat_max_len' parameter, as having this too small can screw up your results.

Hope it helps!

Dave

Comment: Great help, but unfortunately I have a really large data set, beyond max packet size and I can't use group concat in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the BETWEEN clause, just as you have deduced.
Try the following BETWEEN clause instead:

```
WHERE  numerated_rows.rownum  BETWEEN ( middle_rows.median - 1.0001 ) AND ( middle_rows.median - 0.0001) )
```